# one-to-many in SonataUser Bundle

Tags: sonata-admin

Is there a less hacky way?

I need to clear/set some one-to-many relationship, without remove orphans, default behavior doesn't remove neither add related entities, after submit all remains the same.

/.../UserBundle/Admin/OrganizacionAdmin.php
....

```
public function prePersist($organizacion)
{
    $this->preUpdate($organizacion,true);
}


public function preUpdate($organizacion,$agregar=false)
{
    $organizacion->setDependencias($organizacion->getDependencias());
    foreach($organizacion->getDependencias() as $dependencia){
        $dependencia->setOrganizacion($organizacion);
    }
    if($agregar===false){
        $repositorio=$this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('GoproUserBundle:Dependencia');
        $dependenciasRepositorio=$repositorio->findBy(['organizacion'=>$organizacion->getId()]);

        foreach($dependenciasRepositorio as $dr):
            if(!$organizacion->getDependencias()->contains($dr)){
                $dr->setOrganizacion(null);
            }
        endforeach;

    }

}
```

/.../UserBundle/Admin/OrganizacionAdmin.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Dependencia", mappedBy="organizacion", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $dependencias;

public function setDependencias($dependencias)
{
    if (count($dependencias) > 0) {
        foreach ($dependencias as $dependencia) {
            $this->addDependencia($dependencia);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

/.../UserBundle/Admin/DependenciaAdmin.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Organizacion", inversedBy="dependencias")
 */
protected $organizacion;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following methods

```
public function setDependencias($dependencias)
{
    if (count($dependencias) > 0) {
        foreach ($dependencias as $i) {
            $this->addDependencia($i);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function addDependencia($dependencia)
{
    $dependencia->setOrganizacion($this);
    $this->dependencias->add($dependencia);
}

public function removeDependencia($dependencia)
{
    $this->dependencias->removeElement($dependencia);
}
```

... and in the admin class ...

```
public function prePersist($organizacion)
{
    $this->preUpdate($organizacion);
}

public function preUpdate($organizacion)
{
    $organizacion->setDependencias($organizacion->getDependencias());
}
```

... as shown in [One to Many relations and add/edit form in SonataAdmin and Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010849/one-to-many-relations-and-add-edit-form-in-sonataadmin-and-symfony2) and [Sonata Admin Bundle One-to-Many relationship not saving foreign ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993733/sonata-admin-bundle-one-to-many-relationship-not-saving-foreign-id)

The problem here (I asked for it today on [One to Many relations and add/edit form in SonataAdmin and Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010849/one-to-many-relations-and-add-edit-form-in-sonataadmin-and-symfony2/24015431#24015431) ) is that with this implementation you can't clear relationships (any clue?).

Hope this helps....