# Custom entity in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Maybe I'm approaching my whole problem completely wrong, but hopefully someone will understand my struggle and can point me in the right direction.

I want to get some values from my entity Student\Preference in my entity Student so I can load them in a Listmapper.

In my entity Student I have this:

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Map\Bundle\StudentBundle\Entity\Student\Preference", mappedBy="student")
     */
    protected $status;

  /**
     * Get Status
     *
     * @param \Map\Bundle\StudentBundle\Entity\Student\Preference $preference
     * @return string
     */

// When I change $preference to null here I get an error that my instance must be an object of Entity\Student\Preference , but none was given

 public function getStatus(\Map\Bundle\StudentBundle\Entity\Student\Preference $preference = null)
 {
     $string = '';

     $string .= ($preference->getVoorrangChecked() ? "Declined" : "Accepted");
     $string .= "by";
     $string .= $preference->getControleur();
     $string .= "at";
     $string .= $preference->getDateUpdated();

     return $string;
 }
```

But somehow it doesn't recognize $preference.
It gives me this error:

```
Error: Call to a member function getPreferenceChecked() on null
```

But in my entity Student\Preference I certainly have all those functions. Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm really stuck here..
Am I overseeing something, did I forget something?

This is my listMapper:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
        $listMapper
            ->add('remote')
            ->add('name')
            ->add('dobformatted', null, array('label' => 'Birthday'))
            ->add('status');  //Here is where the string generated by getStatus should be
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your function declaration to:

`public function getStatus(\Map\Bundle\StudentBundle\Entity\Student\Preference $preference)`

By adding the `= null` at the end of your parameter, you are making Preference an optional argument.  If you don't pass anything in, the value of `$preference` will be `null`.  So at that point you don't have a Preference object and cannot call member functions to it.

Since your function requires the exist of a Preference object, you don't want to make it optional.  Also, when you're building the string I noticed you don't have the appropriate spacing.  You'll get strings like `DeclinedbySomethingat2015-01-01` instead of `Declined by Something at 2015-01-01`. You'll want to add that in.  You could also use [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
 $string .= ($preference->getVoorrangChecked() ? "Declined" : "Accepted");
 $string .= " by ";
 $string .= $preference->getControleur();
 $string .= " at ";
 $string .= $preference->getDateUpdated();
```

or

```
return sprintf("%s by %s at %s",
    ($preference->getVoorrangChecked() ? "Declined" : "Accepted"),
     $preference->getControleur(),
     $preference->getDateUpdated()
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your clear answer, but when I remove = null it gives me a warning that getStatus() must be an instance of Maps\Bundle\StudentBundle\Entity\Student\Preference, none given..

Comment: Right, that's what you want.  You need to pass a Preference object to the function or it won't work. Your call should look like `getStatus($preference);`

Comment: Hm.. I understand that, but how can I get this value into my listMapper, you can only use fields declared in your entity there right?

Comment: Oh, you're using a Sonata bundle.  You're `getStatus()` function should only contain one line, `return $this->status;` - it needs a proper getter/setter for the bundle.

Comment: Actually since it's a OneToMany, you need to configure it as such.  I'd recommend using Doctrine to generate your entities.  By your definition you can have more than one 'status' per Student.  If that's what you want, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993733/sonata-admin-bundle-one-to-many-relationship-not-saving-foreign-id .  If it should just be a OneToOne, you should change it to that.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it a bit different,

In my listMapper I added:

```
 $listMapper
            ->add('remote')
            ->add('name')
            ->add('dobformatted', null, array('label' => 'Birthday'))
            ->add('preference', 'string', array('template' => 'StudentBundle:CRUD:list_field_status.html.twig'));
```

In my entity:

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Map\Bundle\StudentBundle\Entity\Student\Preference", mappedBy="student")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"preference_id" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $preference;


/**
 * @param mixed $preference
 */
public function setPreference($preference)
{
    $this->preference = $preference;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getPreference()
{
    return $this->preference;
}
```

And in a new twig for this field:

```
{% if object.preference.getControleur is not null %}
<td>{{ "%s by %s at %s"| format((object.preference.getPreferenceChecked ? "Declined" : "Accepted") , object.preference.getControleur, object.preference.getDateUpdated|date('Y-m-d')) }}</td>
{% else %}
<td>Not checked yet.</td>
{% endif %}
```

I hope this will help someone out one day.